# Combinatorics/probability dinner party type problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

At a banquet, 9 women and 6 men are to be seated in a row of 15 chairs. If the entire seating arrangement is to be chosen at random, what is the probability that all of the men will be seated next to each other in 6 consecutive positions?

The correct answer is $\displaystyle \frac{6! 10!}{15!}$. Why is it not $\displaystyle \frac{6! 9!}{15!}$?

It seems to me it should be, because, there are $15!$ total possible ways to order 15 people without regard to order. Then, $6!$ ways of filling the first 6 chairs, and $9!$ ways of filling the rest. So, it should be $6! 9!$ divided by $15!$. Where does the $10!$ come from, and what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the question were

> At a banquet, 9 women and 6 men are to be seated in a row of 15 chairs. If the entire seating arrangement is to be chosen at random, what is the probability that all the men will be seated *in the first 6 seats*?

However, the men can be seated anywhere. In particular, there are $10$ positions where the series of men could start (i.e. after 0 women, after 1 woman, after 2 women, $\ldots$, after 9 women). Then, once you know the $6$ positions where the men could sit, there are $6!$ ways to arrange the men therein and $9!$ ways to arrange the women in the other seats; thus there are
$6!9!\cdot 10 = 6!10!$
ways to seat everyone.

Comment: That concern had crossed my mind, too, that what I was doing would only work if the men were seated in the first 6 positions. Glad to know that this is how you take care of the cases where they don't have to be there.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to view this problem is:

Put the $6$ men in order ($6!$ ways).

Now consider the $6$ ordered men as a single unit.

Arrange the $10$ items ($9$ women and one block of $6$ ordered men) in some order. ($10!$ ways).

Answer (score 3):

A more clear solution would be
$$P = \frac{6! 9! \cdot 10}{15!}$$
The $10$ are the ten batches of $6$ consecutive chairs in the row of $15$. The first man could sit in any chair $k$ such that the following five chairs $k+1, \ldots, k+5$ exist. Thus $k$ must be between $1$ and $15-5 = 10$